# Open file over ssh in local X window

Tags: ssh, files

How can I open html file in local internet browser? I am connected under `/ssh://user@server...`.

I'm thinking about something like `firefox file_from_remote_server`.

Comment: If X is forwarded that should work, why don't you just try?

Comment: How can I open it in Midnight Commander?

Comment: In a local browser? That would require an application which supports SFTP (and I don't think Firefox does).

Comment: You can use `lynx` for text based internet browser or setup xwindow and then output firefox GUI to your xwindow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like SSHFS. Look at e.g.:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh